# How to update my Nginx with yum on CentOS 7

Tags: nginx, yum, http2

I used `yum install nginx` on my ECS server, but the version is not high enough to support http2. After googling around, I added a config file:

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
```

With the content:

```
[nginx]  
name=nginx repo  
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/$releasever/$basearch/  
gpgcheck=0  
enabled=1
```

Then I run `yum update nginx`, which gave me the version 1.8.1, which is still not high enough to support http2.

Can anyone help me update my nginx to version 1.9.5 or higher, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update your config file to this

```
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/centos/$releasever/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

you need the mainline repository

Comment: What do you type instead of `$releasever` and `$basearch`?

Comment: @Pathros these are handled by Yum to make sure it downloads the correct version for your distribution. So you don't need to replace them. See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-using_yum_variables

Comment: @justcompile after changing the `nginx.repo` file to that content, with mainline branch, I still get nginx 1.14.1 as the latest nginx on a fresh install of CentOS 8. On another server with the same nginx.repo file, when I do `yum list nginx --showduplicates` I get all the modern nginx servers including 1.16.1 and 1.18.0. How does that work?